# initializing basic stack, but errors i do not comprehend

Tags: oop, python-3.x, stack

i am trying to initialize a basic stack - with push, and pop function.
the problems comes in while testing. you will notice in the code that i have pushed 2 times, so a print of the stack should display `[5,5]` whereas it is displaying `None`. I could tinker with the code to make it work eventually, but then i will not fully understand the underlying concepts and the error of my ways. so i ask for advice and pointers.
please check out these codes and tell me what i am doing wrong.

this is the code with the class with all it's functions, it is named `stack_class`:

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self._values = []
        print ('Stack initialized...')
        return

    def push(self, var):
        ok = self._values.append(var)
        return ok

    def pop(self):
        self.stack.pop()

    def __str__(self):
        output = "{0}".format(self.ok)
        return output
```

this is the testing code:

```
from stack_class import Stack

ob_1 = Stack()
ob_1.push(5)
print(ob_1.push(5))
```

Comment: also, why does every constructor conventionally have an empty return statement? what is it returning exactly?

Comment: They don't, not in my experience. There's no need for an empty `return` statement at the end of a constructor. A plain `return` statement returns `None`. As does simply falling off the end of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that `append` method doesn't return anything.

```
print [].append(1)
>>> None
```

It does its job, but doesn't return anything, that's why you are getting `None` in variable `ok`. I think you want to return the `_values` instead:

```
def push(self, var):
    self._values.append(var)
    return self._values
```

**Output:**

```
Stack initialized...
[5, 5]
```

Also, it's the first time I read about *empty return convention*. It's not necessary.

Comment: thanks man, i get it now. one last question. do we HAVE to use self._values? why can't we use any other variable? what if there are multiples values to be considered? i tried it with another variable, but the code doesn't work.

Comment: You can change it, it doesn't mather. But **remember** to rename *every* name where `_values` appears.

Answer (score 0):

In your testing code you are not printing the stack by executing `print(ob_1.push(5))`.  What this does is trigger the push function to insert another 5 into your stack.  To print the stack contents just use the name of the stack:

`print(ob_1)`

This will return the stack contents: `[5,5]`